# My HTML header gets messed up when I zoom in and out

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created Header.html page, while zoom-in & out it is getting distorted, could you please help me
I have try to use mostly In-line styling,  because the is differences the styling of few screen and others screen, and if I try to make those screen common styling it is causing a lot of corrections
so im not doing that as of now , Looking for some other options
would you be able to help me here:
here is the html :

```
<body>
<div
  class="row"
  th:fragment="header"
  th:object="${documentsDetailsVM}"
  style="
    background-color: #2196f3 !important;
    font-family: Roboto, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont;
    font-size: 0.8125rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: 60px;
  "
>
  <div
    class="col-md-8"
    style="
      padding-left: 40%;
      font-family: Roboto, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI,
        Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
        line-height: 60px;
    "
  >
    <!--    <div class="container justify-content-md-center">-->
    <a
      th:href="@{/documents/home}"
      class="navbar-brand mx-auto"
      id="homePageRedirect"
      style="pointer-events: none"
    >
      <!-- Logo Image -->
      <img
        th:src="@{/images/Aon_Corporation_logo.svg}"
        width="45"
        alt=""
        class="d-inline-block align-middle mr-2"
      />
      <span class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-white"
        >Documents Editor</span
      >
    </a>
  </div>
  <!--       th:if="${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')}"-->
  <!-- Tenants Select Dropdown Element-->
  <div   th:if="${documentsDetailsVM != null}" class="col-md-1" style="padding-top: .7%" sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
    <span th:fragment="view-all-tenants">
      <form
        style="
          font-size: 13px;
          height: 20px;
          width: 100px;
          padding: 0;
          text-align: center;
          font-size: 12px;
          font-family: Roboto, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI,
            Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
        "
      >
        <div>
          <strong style="color: white">Tenants</strong>
          <select
            id="selectTenants"
            required
            style="width: 100%; text-align: center; padding: 0"
          ></select>
          <input type="hidden" name="selectTenants" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div  th:if="${documentsDetailsVM != null}" class="col-md-2" style="height: 100%;margin-top: 1.0%;padding-left: 5%; font-size: 12px;
        
  font-family: Roboto, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI,
    Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: white;"  sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
    <div class="row">
        <strong>User Name: </strong>
        <span th:utext="*{loggedInUser.firstName}"></span>
        <span th:utext="| *{loggedInUser.lastName}|">
            User Name: First Last</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <strong>User Id: </strong>
        <span id="loggedInUserId" th:utext="*{loggedInUser.loggedInUserId}">User Id: first</span>
        <input id="defaultTenantId" type="hidden" th:value="*{loggedInUser.defaultTenant.id}"/>
    </div>
    <span
      th:fragment="user-info">
   <strong hidden>PAS Id: </strong
      ><span th:utext="*{loggedInUser.pasId}" hidden>PAS Id: first</span>
      <span> </span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div
    class="col-md-1" th:if="${documentsDetailsVM != null}"
    style="
      font-family: Roboto, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI,
        Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
      padding-top: 2%;
      font-size: 12px;
    "
  >
    <a
      id="logoutButton"
      sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"
      href="javascript:$('#form').submit();"
    >
      <span
        class="zmdi zmdi-sign-in"
        style="color: white; font-size: 12px"
        aria-hidden="true"
      ></span
      >&nbsp;<span class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-white"
        >Logout</span
      >
    </a>
    <form
      style="visibility: hidden"
      id="form"
      th:method="post"
      action="#"
      th:action="@{/logout}"
    ></form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware which `version of Bootstrap` you are using. I have added `Bootstrap 4` `cdn link` and have edited your `html` and made it `responsive`. Please check now. To view the result just copy paste my `html` as shown below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.1.1/css/brands.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        strong {
            color: black !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row py-2" th:fragment="header" th:object="${documentsDetailsVM}" style="
    background-color: #2196f3 !important;
    font-family: Roboto, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont;
    font-size: 0.8125rem;
    font-weight: 400;
  ">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xl-6 text-right" style="
      font-family: Roboto, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI,
        Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
        
    ">
                <!--    <div class="container justify-content-md-center">-->
                <a th:href="@{/documents/home}" class="navbar-brand mx-auto" id="homePageRedirect"
                    style="pointer-events: none">
                    <!-- Logo Image -->
                    <img th:src="@{/images/Aon_Corporation_logo.svg}" width="45" alt=""
                        class="d-inline-block align-middle mr-2" />
                    <span class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-white">Documents Editor</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <!--       th:if="${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')}"-->
            <!-- Tenants Select Dropdown Element-->
            <div th:if="${documentsDetailsVM != null}" class="col-md-3 col-xl-2" sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
                <span th:fragment="view-all-tenants">
                    <form style="
          padding: 0;
          font-size: 12px;
          font-family: Roboto, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI,
            Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
        ">
                        <div class="mb-2">
                            <strong style="color: white">Tenants</strong>
                            <select id="selectTenants" required
                                style="width: 100%; text-align: center; padding: 0"></select>
                            <input type="hidden" name="selectTenants" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div th:if="${documentsDetailsVM != null}" class="col-md-3 col-xl-3" style="height: 100%; font-size: 12px;
        
  font-family: Roboto, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI,
    Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: white;" sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <strong>User Name: </strong>
                        <span th:utext="*{loggedInUser.firstName}"></span>
                        <span th:utext="| *{loggedInUser.lastName}|">
                            User Name: First Last</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <strong>User Id: </strong>
                        <span id="loggedInUserId" th:utext="*{loggedInUser.loggedInUserId}">User Id: first</span>
                        <input id="defaultTenantId" type="hidden" th:value="*{loggedInUser.defaultTenant.id}" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span th:fragment="user-info">
                    <strong hidden>PAS Id: </strong><span th:utext="*{loggedInUser.pasId}" hidden>PAS Id: first</span>
                    <span> </span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 text-right d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end"
                th:if="${documentsDetailsVM != null}" style="
      font-family: Roboto, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI,
        Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 12px;
    ">
                <a id="logoutButton" sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" href="javascript:$('#form').submit();">
                    <span class="zmdi zmdi-sign-in" style="color: white; font-size: 12px"
                        aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;<span
                        class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-white">Logout</span>
                </a>
                <form style="visibility: hidden" id="form" th:method="post" action="#" th:action="@{/logout}"></form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```